# Replicate Server - Report Server

Tags: database, server, report, replicate

Could I use the Replicate Server as a Report Server?
Because I listen to my friends that use Replicate Server as Report Server is nonsense, It likes backup than report. I'm not sure about it. I tried to find this information but I can't figure it out.
Thanks.

I tried to create a Replicate Server, because Main Server (Server store applications data)'s CPU always High (use many query to select to report). I would like to reduce cpu usage for Main Server.